# SQL Backup & Dropbox Uploader bash script won't exit and takes up resources

Tags: bash, cron

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2
 3 USER="root"
 4 PASSWORD="??"
 5 OUTPUT="/home/northfolk28/SQLbackup"
 6 UPLOADER="/home/northfolk28/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh"
 7
 8 rm $OUTPUT/*.gz > /dev/null 2>&1
 9 echo "Deleted previous .gz"
10
11 databases=`mysql --user=root --password=?? -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`
12
13 for db in $databases; do
14     if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
15         echo "Dumping database: $db"
16         mysqldump --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $db > $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
17         gzip $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
18         $UPLOADER upload $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql.gz /SQLbackup/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql.gz
19     fi
20 done
```

I made backup script that automatically backs up SQL databases and uploads it on dropbox.
I used Dropbox-Uploader
(https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader).

It works perfectly when I excute it on bash but when it runs on cron, the backup is done but the script won't exit and takes up resources forever. Like.. 4gb of disk and 30% of CPU usage per process??

On htop it displays

```
bash /home/northfolk28/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh /home/northfolk28/SQLbackup (date).mysql.sql.gz
```

OS is ubuntu server 14.04, I just put the script on /etc/cron.daily
Any wrong on the script??

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I am having the same issue

Comment: No, I gave up and removed the dropbox part.

Comment: I just worked out what it was and answered the question! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the reason this is happening (well the reason it was with me) is that within a cron job you don't have access to the fill $PATH variable. Therefore you need to add an additional parameter to the call to tell the dropbox uploader where the config file is, eg:

$DROPBOX_UPLOADER_SCRIPT **-f /home/username/.dropbox_uploader** upload $ZIP_FILE_NAME $DROPBOX_LOCATION

Comment: No Worries, can you accept the answer for future people viewing :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue close to that. When using % in the CRON, you need to escape it as explained there http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/

I'm not sure it applies in your case, but you could try :

`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.$db.sql.gz

Comment: No luck... % is ok when it's on the seprate file. Still thanks for the answer.